# Why Actions class not compatible with Firefox browser

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, geckodriver, qaf

My Configurations :

> ```
> selenium v 3.13.0 
> geckodriver 0.21.0
> Firefox version 61.0.1
> ```

I have below kind of menu in my application where i have to hover on category and then have to choose a product :

[image]

And I'm using Actions class to performing the action. Using below code

```
@QAFTestStep(stepName = "navigateToCategoryProduct", description = "navigate to product name {0} under product category {1}")
    public void navigateToCategoryProduct(String product, String category)
            throws InterruptedException {
        new Actions(getDriver()).moveToElement(getCategory(category)).pause(500)
                .moveToElement(getProduct(category, product)).click().build().perform();

    }

    public QAFWebElement getCategory(String category) {
        return new QAFExtendedWebElement(String.format(ConfigurationManager.getBundle()
                .getString("header.navigation.category.link"), category));
    }

    public QAFWebElement getProduct(String category, String product) {
        return new QAFExtendedWebElement(String.format(ConfigurationManager.getBundle()
                .getString("header.navigation.product.link"), category, product));
    }
```

So everything is smoothly with Chrome (using v68.0). but while same script to be used in Firefox it is hovering `Food` category and selecting the product from `Weight Loss` category. I'm scratching my head to find an alternative how do i make this browser compatible.

I have tried with explicit/implicit/hard coded wait even but no success. Any alternative for Action class which i can implement to hover and select the submenu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After replacing my code with below code segment, started working for me.

```
Actions action = new Actions(getDriver()); 
action.moveToElement(getCategory(category)).build().perform();
waitForPresent(String.format(ConfigurationManager.getBundle().getString("header.navigation.product.link"), category, product));
getProduct(category, product).click();
```

It seems building all action in same step was causing issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have added example for Firefox:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51823909/why-actions-class-not-compatible-with-firefox-browser");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        actions.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#question-header > div > a"))).pause(3).click().perform();
    }
}
```

and it works. Have a look on your code more in details. Try to debug it.

Comment: Thanks for response. but it didn't work. Although My script is working fine for some other menu selection. but failing for  few selected testcase. and i have inspected them but not found something special which cause failure.